# How to delete the cookies from different domains?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, .net-6.0

I need to delete all cookies from two different domains to proceed with the logout. This is because I use load balancing to authenticate in SSO and access my web app.

I need to delete the cookies from `.domain1.com` and `.domain2.com`.

How can I do this using .NET 6?

I've been trying this code, but it's not working:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    DeleteAllCookiesFromDomains(HttpContext, ".domain1.com");
    return redirect("https....");
}

public void DeleteAllCookiesFromDomains(HttpContext httpContext, params string[] domains)
{
    foreach (var cookieKey in httpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys)
    {
        if (domains.Any(domain => cookieKey.StartsWith(domain)))
        {
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookieKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your cookies have a `Path` different from `/`? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46158

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "delete all cookies from two different domains"? Do you want the server hosted on `.domain1.com` to be able to remove cookies for `.domain2.com`? I'm pretty sure it's impossible. You probably don't want a news site, for example, to remove your bank's auth cookie, right?